# Child sprite not moving along with Parent - AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to make a game where I have a parent sprite and a child sprite attached to it. I want the parent sprite move from bottom to top (which is done successfully) but the problem is the child sprite is not moving along with the parent. It stays at the bottom of the screen. following is the code responsible for attaching the sprites.

```
float points[] = parent.convertSceneToLocalCoordinates(0, 0);
child.setPosition(points[0], points[1]);
            mScene.attachChild(parent);
            parent.attachChild(child);
            mScene.registerTouchArea(parent); 
            mScene.registerTouchArea(child); 
            parent.setZIndex(0);
            child.setZIndex(1);
```

While creating child sprite I am using just 0,0 as co-ordinates.
I am moving the parent on a path using "Path".
Another thing to mention is that parent is a "Sprite" and child is "AnimatedSprite"

Comment: Hi,

I think this is because touch areas are in the order that you register them (Z index is not related to touch area).

Try using setOnAreaTouchTraversalFrontToBack() in your scene.

Comment: That didn't help. I think the function you mentioned is to change the index but my problem is that even after attaching child sprite to parent it doesn't move along with parent and stays at the point of creation.

Comment: remove the following  line  mScene.registerTouchArea(child); and also comment z order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mScene.attachChild(parent);
parent.attachChild(child);
mScene.registerTouchArea(parent); 
//mScene.registerTouchArea(child); 
//parent.setZIndex(0);
parent.registerEntityModifier();
//child.setZIndex(1);
```